# addActionListener for a button array?

Tags: java

Hello I'm trying to do a ratsuk game that is chess but only with the knight.

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Knight {
    private Icon image;
    private int w;
    private int k;
    private Random rand;

    public Knight() {
        image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("redKnight.gif"));
        w = rand.nextInt(9);
        k = rand.nextInt(9);
    }

    public void Caballo(JButton[][] matriz, int i, int j) {
        matriz[i][j].setIcon(image);

        matriz[i][j].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //Execute when button is pressed
                matriz[i][j].setBackground(Color.RED);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So I was trying to do a recursive method which I am not really sure will work.
But the problem is that inside the `addActionListener`, netbeans tells me that the variables have to be final which I don't really get why. Once I run it the image doesn't show at all

Here is the rest of the code

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.util.Random;

public class Tablero {
    private JButton[][] mesa;
    private Random rad;
    public Tablero() {
        mesa = new JButton[8][8];
    }

    public void cuadriculado(JFrame ventana) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(8, 8, 0, 0));

        for (int i = 0; i < mesa.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mesa[0].length; j++) {
                mesa[i][j] = new JButton();
                mesa[i][j].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40));
                panel.add(mesa[i][j]);

            }
        }
        for (int r = 0; r < mesa.length; r++) {
            for (int t = 0; t < mesa[0].length; t++) {
                if (r % 2 == 0 || r == 0) {
                    if (t % 2 == 0 || t == 0) {
                        mesa[r][t].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                    } else {
                        mesa[r][t].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (t % 2 == 0 || t == 0) {
                        mesa[r][t].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                    } else {
                        mesa[r][t].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        ventana.setContentPane(panel);
        ventana.setSize(500, 500);
        ventana.setVisible(true);
        Knight kn =new Knight();

        kn.Caballo(mesa, rad.nextInt(9), rad.nextInt(9));
    }
}
```

Any help will greatly appreciated. I am really new to Java and none of this was explained to me, so I have been struggling a lot.

Comment: What exactly is the problem ?

Comment: why this method signature `public void Caballo(JButton[][] matriz, int i, int j)` instead of  `public void Caballo(JButton button)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
matriz[i][j].setBackground(Color.RED);
```

You are trying to access "matriz" from an annonymous inner class so the variable needs to either be a class variable or a final variable.

I would question why you made this method belong to the Knight class. This method should be part of the `Tablero` class since that is where you define the array as a class variable. Then you won't have the compiler problem.

But if you really want to keep the method in the Knight class then the code should be:

```
public void Caballo(**final** JButton[][] matriz, int i, int j) {
```

> Once i run it the image doesnt show at all

```
image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("redKnight.gif"));
```

You just create an Icon. You need to add it to a label and then add the label to the GUI.

> i am really new to java and nothing of this was explained to me

Start by reading the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). Maybe the section on `How to Use Icons` would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this

```
public void Caballo(JButton[][] matriz, int i, int j)
```

to this

```
public void Caballo(final JButton[][] matriz, final int i, final int j)
```

The reason the variables need to final is because they are accessed inside the ActionListener's actionPerformed. Java needs to know that these variables arent going to change before it gets to use them. It goes back to a Java Garbage collector thing that I would prefer not ramble on about, but that's the jest of it.